# Complexity of the Transductive SVM training problem

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, machine-learning, svm

The [Transductive Support Vector Machine training problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine#Transductive_support_vector_machines) is a non-convex mixed integer programming problem:

> **Transductive Support Vector Machine training problem.**
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \mathop{\text{minimize}}_{\xi,\theta,b,u} \;&\|\theta\|^2 + C \sum_{i=1}^{m+k} \xi_i \\[1ex]
> \text{subject to:}\;
> &y^{(i)}(\theta^T x^{(i)}-b) \geqslant 1-\xi_i, \quad\text{for } \; i=1, \ldots, m\\
> &u_i\;\;(\theta^T x^{(i)}-b) \geqslant 1-\xi_i, \quad\text{for }\; i=m, \ldots, m+k\\
> &u_i \in \{-1, 1\}\\
> &\xi_i \geqslant 0
> \end{align}
> $$
>   where $C > 0$, and:
>
> - $x^{(1)},\dots,x^{(m+k)} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are data points;
> - $y^{(1)},\dots,y^{(m)} \in \{-1, 1\}$ are labels provided for $1 \leqslant i \leqslant m$ 
>   (the vectors $x^{(i)}$ are missing labels for $i > m$).

If I recall correctly, it can be proved that this problem is NP-hard, but I can't find a reference to that claim.

**Questions.**

- Is it really NP-hard?
- Is it APX-complete?

Comment: The $NP$-hardness result is folklore since this non convex problem can encode integer linear programming which is $NP$-complete.

Comment: Although I find this intuitively plausible, it's not obvious to me how to encode an arbitrary integer linear programming problem into a transductive SVM training problem.
May you please explain how it's done?